# Will WebFlux have any bottlenecks in such architecture?

Tags: mongodb, rest, netty, spring-webflux

We're currently about to migrate from monolithic design to the microservice architecture, trying to choose the best way to replace `JAX-WS` with `RESTful` and considering to use `Spring WebFlux`.

We currently have an `JAX-WS` endpoint deployed at `Tomcat EE` serving requests from third-party clients. Webservice endpoint makes a long running blocking call to the database and then sends a SOAP-response to the client with a data retrieved from DB (`Oracle`).

`Oracle DB` will be replaced with one of `NoSQL` databases soon (possibly it will be `MongoDB`). Since `MongoDB` supports asynchronous calls we're considering to substitute current implementation with a microservice exposing `REST` endpoint based on `WebFlux`.

We have about 2500 req/sec at peaks, so current endpoint often gets down with a `OutOfMemoryError`. It was a root cause that pushed us towards migration.

My thoughts are to create a non-blocking endpoint which will call `MongoDB` in asynchronous manner and send a REST-response to the client. So I have a few questions considering basic features that `WebFlux` provides:

1. As far as I concerned there is a built-in backpressure control at
   the business-level (not TCP flow control) in `WebFlux` and it works
   generally via `Reactive Streams`. Since our clients are not
   reactive, does it means that such way of a backpressure control is
   not implementable here?
2. Suppose that calls to a new database remains long-running in a new
   architecture. Since `Netty` uses `EventLoop` to serve incoming
   requests, is there possible a situation when the microservice has
   accepted all incoming HTTP connections, invoke an async call to the
   `db` and subscribed a resulted `Mono` to the scheduler, but, since
   the request quantity keeps growing explosively, application keep
   creating new `workers` at `scheduler` pools that leads to a
   crashing? Is this a realistic scenario?
3. Suppose that calls to the database remained synchronous. Is there a
   way to handle them using `WebFlux` in a such way that microservice
   will remain reachable under load?
4. Which bottlenecks can be found in such design? Does this solution
   looks adequate?
5. Does `Netty` (or `Reactor-Netty`, or whatever) has a tool to limit a
   quantity of requests processing simultaneously? Say I would to limit
   the endpoint to serve not more than 100 parallel requests and skip
   all requests above that point, is it possible?
6. Suppose I will create a huge amount of threads serving async (or
   maybe sync) calls to the `DB`. Where is a breaking point when the
   application will crash or stop responding to the incoming
   HTTP-requests? What will happened there - we will ran out of memory
   or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, there were no any major issues concerning perfomance during our pilot project. But unfortunately we didn't take in account some specific Linux (and also OpenShift) TCP tuning props.

They may significanly affect the overall perfomance, in our case we've gained about 10 times more requests after tuning.

So pay attention to the `net.core.somaxconn` and other related parameters.
I've summarized our expertise in the [article.](http://java.msk.ru/experience-in-webflux-netty-highload-optimization/)